# Is it possible to automatically generate multiple subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot

Is it possible to automatically generate multiple subplots in matplotlib? An example of the process I want to automate is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
figure = plt.figure()
ax1 = figure.add_subplot(2, 3, 1)
ax2 = figure.add_subplot(2, 3, 2)
ax3 = figure.add_subplot(2, 3, 3)
ax4 = figure.add_subplot(2, 3, 4)
ax5 = figure.add_subplot(2, 3, 5)
ax6 = figure.add_subplot(2, 3, 6)
```

The subplots need unique names, as this will allow me to do stuff like:

```
for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4, ax5, ax6]:
    ax.set_title("example")
```

Many thanks.

Addition: Are there any functions that automate the generation of multiple subplots? What if I needed to repeat the above process 100 times? Would I have to type out every ax1 to ax100?

Comment: by automatically generate, what do you mean? could you be more specific?

Comment: to generate the above 6 subplots, I believe you can only minimize the code by adding in more `for` loops for your remaining `title,legend etc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2,3)
```

axs will be an array containing the subplots.

Or unpack the array instantly:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4, ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(2,3)
```

Comment: Should the second option should be fig, ([ax1, ax2, ax3], [ax4, ax5, ax6]) = plt.subplots(2,3) or something similar, as axs is a 2x3 array?