# matplotlib multiple plots with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am currently trying to develop a convenience function, which is supposed to create for each column in a pandas dataframe a basic plot with the values and their amount in the dataset for all columns in the dataframe.

```
def plot_value_counts(df, leave_out):
  # is supposed to create the subplots grid where I can add the plots
  fig, axs = plt.subplots(int(len(df)/2) + 1,int(len(df)/2) + 1)
  for idx, name in enumerate(list(df)):
    if name == leave_out:
      continue
    else:
      axs[idx] = df[name].value_counts().plot(kind="bar")
  return fig, axs
```

this snippet runs for ever and never stops.
I tried looking at other similar questions on stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything specific for my case.

the usage of the subplots function came from the following question: [Is it possible to automatically generate multiple subplots in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27185139/is-it-possible-to-automatically-generate-multiple-subplots-in-matplotlib)

below a short sample of the data file, so that everybody can understand the problem:
https://gist.github.com/hentschelpatrick/e0a7e1400a4b5c356ec8b0e4952f8cc1#file-train-csv

Comment: Can you provide a (short!) example of an input for which this process hangs for you?

Comment: @asongtoruin i added a link to the gist with some of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `axis` object in the plot method [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html). And you should iterate on columns:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(int(len(df)/2) + 1,int(len(df)/2) + 1)
for idx, name in enumerate(df.columns):
    if name == leave_out:
        continue
    else:
        df[name].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", ax=axs[idx])
```

**EDIT**: If you have memory issues (doens't seem to run) try first without using subplots and `show` each plot:

```
for idx, name in enumerate(df.columns):
    if name == leave_out:
        continue
    else:
        df[name].value_counts().plot(kind="bar")
        plt.show()
```

Comment: it still runs indefinitely

Comment: The method works, although clearly it doesn't like a 100 subplots. Try passing a single axis / figure with `plt.show()` (see edit)

Comment: I have found the reason why it ran out of memory even though there are just 6 columns. 2 of them are numeric values which arent binned resulting in an extremely overloaded plot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that i had written for my project to plot all columns in a pandas dataframe. It will generate a grid of size nx4 and will plot all the columns

```
def plotAllFeatures(dfData):
    plt.figure(1, figsize=(20,50))
    pos=1
    for feature in dfData.columns:
        plt.subplot(np.ceil(len(dfData.columns)/4),4,pos)
        dfData[feature].plot(title=feature)
        pos=pos+1
    plt.show()
```